# Does DJI mavic-pro supports Follow me on wifi mode

Tags: dji-sdk

I am developing an Android app for Mavic-pro drone in which I need to use the follow me APIs. But in DJI Go app when we connected to the drone by wifi it doesn't shows the follow me feature. Can somebody please confirm whether the drone supports Follow me on wifi mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, DJI Mavic Pro doesn't support Follow Me Mission on WiFi mode. You can check the SDK API Doc of DJIFollowMeMission on DJI Developer Website: http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIFollowMeMission.html#djifollowmemission

*Description:
The class represents a Follow Me mission. In a Follow Me mission, the aircraft is programmed to track and maintain a constant distant relative to some object, such as a person or a moving vehicle. You can use it to make the aircraft follow a GPS device, such as a remote controller with a GPS signal or a mobile device. It is not supported by Mavic Pro when using WiFi connection. It is not supported by Spark.*